# Add HTTP header to SOAP request via groovy-wslite

Tags: soap, groovy

I am trying to add a HTTP header into my SOAP request. The code is written in groovy and is using groovy-wslite library. My code looks like the following:

```
    def client = new SOAPClient(AConfig.url)
    client.httpClient.sslTrustStoreFile = abcd
    client.httpClient.sslTrustStorePassword =AConfig.password
```

How do I add HTTP header to the client object?

Comment: Documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) which shows an example usage of header.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an HTTP header to the client object itself.

Instead, each SOAP request that the client sends out can have its own set of HTTP headers added to it.

The first parameter to the *send* method can contain the HTTP headers. Here is an example:

```java
String content = "<....SOAP message body here...>"
SOAPClient client = new SOAPClient(AConfig.url)

Map requestParams = [ headers: [ CustomHeader: "My custom header" ] ]
client.send(requestParams, content)
```